# Can I save a sqlite Database in memory?

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite, memory

Can I save a sqlite Database in memory?
I want to save my db into my phone memory.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes, this question seems fine.

Answer (score 5):

By default Sqlite database get stored in **app memory** (/data/data/pkgname/databases/mydb.db). If you want you can store database on **internal phone memory** as well as on **sdcard** also.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean *memory* as in *RAM*, [SQLite supports in-memory databases](https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html). You need to use the magic filename `:memory:`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can save into memory. But it depends which memory you want to save
RAM/ROM

if RAM then use ":memory" concept of sq-lite
if ROM then give the database name while creating the database in android